# How to align the position of two objects with each other

Tags: transforms, photogrammetry

I have two different meshes representing the same object (objects obtained from photogrammetry).

Simple example:
[image]

The meshes of these objects are complex and have many vertices. How can I position both objects in the same location so that the position of the vertices selected by me in object 1 is the same as in object 2?

I'm looking for adjustment something like in this question, but there are only three points being set, and that might not necessarily help me(scaling alone based on three reference points may not be sufficient in my case.
):

[What is the easiest way to move object using 3 points (to have same transform for two objects)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244127/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-move-object-using-3-points-to-have-same-transform-fo)

Additional example:

I'm interested in aligning models with respect to specific vertices - let me give you a concrete example. I have two object meshes representing the same object - a residential building. These models were obtained using photogrammetry, so they slightly differ from each other (one model may have parts missing that the other has, and vice versa). I would like to align their positions based on the key points of the building (corners, roof peak, etc.) so that the positions of both models overlap, allowing me to easily fill in the gaps in one model based on fragments from the other model in the future.

Comment: maybe i understood you wrong, but if i look at your picture, i would say: this is mathematically impossible. e.g. if distance between E F and J are different, you will (except in rare cases) never get them on same position without moving vertices. And you wrote (align position of two objects - not vertices). So maybe you wanna change the question to make it more clear what you want...?

Comment: @Chris I've added an additional example in the problem description.

Comment: "so that the position of the vertices selected by me in object 1 is the same as in object 2?" -> this sentence makes it impossible to do that. But...what you could ask is: how could i align the objects by the faces which are built by the 6 vertices of the two objects. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to achieve

Comment: this is a duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156443/how-to-snap-and-align-2-objects